# Pass parameter into directive callback using scope.$eval

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a mouse-wheel directive that is called when the mouse is moved. But how do I pass the scroll position during the callback?

```
export function ngMouseWheelDown() {
    return function (scope: angular.IScope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel onmousewheel",
            function (event) {

                // cross-browser wheel delta
                var event = window.event || event; // old IE support
                var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.wheelDelta || -event.detail)));

                if (delta < 0) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.ngMouseWheelDown);
                    });
                }
            });
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-mouse-wheel-up="$ctrl.scrollEvent($event)"
     ng-mouse-wheel-down="$ctrl.scrollEvent($event)"
     style="overflow-y: auto;">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `locals` argument of the `$eval` method:

```
export function ngMouseWheelDown() {
    return function (scope: angular.IScope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel onmousewheel",
            function (event) {

                // cross-browser wheel delta
                var event = window.event || event; // old IE support
                var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.wheelDelta || -event.detail)));

                if (delta < 0) {
                    var locals = {$event: event, $delta: delta};
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.ngMouseWheelDown, locals);
                    });
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-mouse-wheel-up="$ctrl.scrollEvent($event, $delta)"
     ng-mouse-wheel-down="$ctrl.scrollEvent($event, $delta)"
     style="overflow-y: auto;">
```

For more information, see
- [AngularJS scope.$eval API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need eval. AngularJs has bindings - ability to evaluate and  pass anything you want from parent to child (from the controller to directive) All you need is to create scoped directive like here:

```
return {
    scope: {handler: '='},
    link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs){
                 element.bind("", function(event){
                         ...
                         $scope.handler(...);
                  })
           }
}
```

But as @georgeawg mentioned, it is not always a good idea to create an isolated scope, because, in one element you can have only one isolated scope.

So, for that purposes, you can use [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service to evaluate your callback from the attributes:

```
['$parse', function myDirective($parse){return {
     link: function myDirecitveLink($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
               // this is the only expression that can be evaluated whenever 
               // you need
               const handlerExpression = $parse($attrs['myHandlerName']); 

               // this is real handler you can call and pass params
               const readlHandler = handlerExpression($scope); 

               // now you can call your handler with desired params
               realHandler(...);
    }
}}]
```

This will also save you some CPU because you will not create new watcher and can fully manage when and how much times you need to evaluate the expression.

@georgeawg Thanks for the comments

Comment: Using isolate scope is not recommended for directives that simply bind events. An element with more than one directive with isolate scope won't work. For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Combining directives with different scope defintions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#combining-directives-with-different-scope-defintions)

Comment: @georgeawg Yep, that's why I've added the article about $parse

Comment: The two-way binding created with the `=` operator also adds isolate scope and two watchers which negatively impacts performance.